# Comp Science Question Divide and conquer

Tags: computer-science

Design a O(n log(n)) time algorithm that computes two indices i and j (where
i ≤ j) for which the sum A[i] + A[i + 1] + · · · + A[j − 1] + A[j] is maximum.
Describe your algorithm in plain English. Moreover, you must use the Divide and-Conquer
approach, write the recursion equation for the time of computation
of your algorithm and solve it.

What i did to start off this question is we are given T(n)=2T(n/5)+√n

=$2(2T(n/(5^2))+√n/5)+√n$
= $4(2T(n/5^3)+√n/5^2)+√n$
=  $8(2T(n/5^4)+√n/5^3)+√n$

etc.

I got stuck here, not sure where to do now.

Comment: Help with MathJax is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It is hard to read your recursion and this will help.  You missed the "Describe your algorithm in plain English" part.  It will be much easier to review the recursion if we know how the algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: If your recurrence relation is right, you can [follow the master (theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Comment: Judging by the recurrence, there's something very fishy about your algorithm choice (Are you sure it's not T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)?)

Comment: It was told to use the T(n) equation as a black box

Comment: Ross i made it look better thanks to your advice.